# Getting an instance of a class that uses dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I've been reading about *dependency injection*, and I'm getting the basics. Most of the examples on the internet explain it till here:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private IDependency _dependency;

    public MyClass(IDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

This way, we inject the *dependency* through the *constructor*. But I don't think it's a good idea to keep writing:

```
var myClassInstance = new MyClass(someArgument);
```

all throughout the code. Should I use the factory pattern to get instances?

```
public static class MyClassFactory
{
    private static IDependency dependency = DependencyFactory.GetInstance();

    public static MyClass GetInstance()
    {
        return new MyClass(dependency);
    }
}
```

Is this the way to go?

I know that using a DI container solves the problem, but I'd like to learn how to incorporate dependency injection in my code, before using a DI container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a factory would be the way to go.  In fact, a DI container is really just a glorified factory that can be configured via xml (in the case of spring for example) or code (for something like structure map)

Comment: An extra question, is it more common practice to keep `MyClassFactory` in the same file as `MyClass`, or in its own file?

Comment: @hattenn - typically I would have it in it's own file.

Answer (score 4):

The dependency injection is just a pattern - you implement it on the first portion of code (constructor injection)

Now you can configure the dependency manually (as you did on the first example) or by using a framework which will help you (behind the scene it will do more or less the same thing).

The value of the pattern is not to avoid writing the below

`var myClassInstance = new MyClass(dependencyObject);`

but is to decouple layers of software that otherwise would be coupled